# What type of connector is this? (bridges two boards by means of a row of rigid, uninsulated wires)

Tags: connector

Trying to repair a friend's older Panasonic LCD TV I came upon this weird type of connector shown in the pic. How is it called and how should I go about disconnecting it without breaking anything?

[image]

Comment: I've seen those before, I don't think they're connectors--at least, not of the sort that can be disconnected without desoldering or cutting. You may want to just desolder it and replace it with a short ribbon cable or something.

Comment: It's just a form of "open wire" ribbon cable. It isn't meant to be disconnected.

Comment: I'm not sure that they are not using connectors. IIRC i've seen such things could be disassembled (soldering two boards together, holding that weird connection, that's convoluted for mass production).

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen an occasional similar connection. Those are exposed leads, so you will want to keep them straight and not touch each other (of course).

You may have to carefully remove both (or all of the connected) boards at the same time, as the "ribbon" was probably soldered in before the PCB's were installed into the chassis at the plant. This is why many of the small time shops may not even want to tackle this kind of repair.

Good luck though, and a worthy project.